# iOS: How to generate public key using decimal X NSData and decimal Y NSData?

Tags: ios, nsdata, public-key-encryption

I have a method like this

```objectivec
+ (NSData *)getPublicKeyFromDecimalX:(NSData *)xInput decimalY:(NSData *)yInput { ... }
```

I know how to generate it when I have `hexX: (NSData*)` like this...

```objectivec
UInt8 iBytes[] = {0x04};
    
NSMutableData *allData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[allData appendBytes:iBytes length:sizeof(iBytes)];
[allData appendData:xInput];
[allData appendData:yInput];

NSMutableDictionary *publicKeyOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[publicKeyOptions setValue:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[publicKeyOptions setValue:(__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass];
[publicKeyOptions setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:256] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];
[publicKeyOptions setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];

SecKeyRef publicKeyRef = SecKeyCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)allData, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)publicKeyOptions, nil);
```

BUT I'm struggling to convert decimal `NSData` into hexadecimal `NSData`.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, as `NSData` is just a buffer of octets. What overarching goal are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm struggling to convert decimal `NSData` into hexadecimal `NSData`.

A `NSData`, itself, is neither decimal or hexadecimal. It is just a series of bytes of data.

Consider

```objectivec
UInt8 bytes[] = {0x2a, 0xff};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSLog(@"%@", data); // {length = 2, bytes = 0x2aff}
```

That is an `NSData` with `0x2a` followed by `0xff`.

If you declare `bytes` in decimal, the `NSData` is identical:

```objectivec
UInt8 bytes[] = {42, 255};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSLog(@"%@", data); // also {length = 2, bytes = 0x2aff}
```

---

Where it gets interesting is the number being represented in the `NSData` is not a series of bytes (i.e. not just a series of 8-bit integers), but a numeric value larger than one byte (e.g. 16-bits, 32-bits, etc.) In this case, we have to worry about the “[endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)” as the decimal value represented in the `NSData`. So, when we store numeric values as a series of bytes, we like to be explicit about the order of the bytes. For example, if we want a big-endian `NSData` representation:

```objectivec
UInt16 value = 11007;
UInt16 bytes = NSSwapHostShortToBig(value);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSLog(@"%@", data); // {length = 2, bytes = 0x2aff}
```

Comment: Thank you, this made sense.